# How to eliminate "unique visitors" information from GoAccess report?

Tags: goaccess

The webserver of which I am off-line analyzing the logs sits behind a proxy server. The IP addresses in the log file are not the ones from the clients but the ones from the hand full of proxy servers. This I cannot change. The parsing works well, but the number of "unique visitors" that GoAccess calculates is therefor not valid. 
How can I eliminate that information from the html reports as it is misleading? I tried to hide the IP address from the analyzer with %^ instead of %h but that leads to an error.

I read the GoAccess manual but I can't find an option to ignore the unique visitors. GoAccess Version is 1.1.1.

Manny thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can. Have you tried parsing the client IP in a [**reverse proxy setup**](https://github.com/allinurl/goaccess/issues/78#issuecomment-247808158)?

Comment: @SijiaDin there is also other reasons for which I cannot have the IP addresses of the clients. e.g. privacy restrictions.